# How to save uploaded file names in json object using CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript

I recently started working with Coffeescript.
In my current project, I wanted to save my clicked buttons and uploaded files into a JSON file/object (for all `<input type="button" />` and `<input type="file" />`).

This works for the `<input type="button" />`, but not for the `<input type="file" />`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/zzd20ye7/).

Comment: Please paste code in ur question.

Comment: fiddle is available in question already, otherwise you can find at: https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/zzd20ye7/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what the code inside your fiddle should do. Please describe your code with some comments.